# Qt Android qApp->primaryScreen()->availableGeometry() return 0x0

Tags: android, c++, qt

When use `qApp->primaryScreen()->availableGeometry();` in the application if I use on desktop (either Linux or Windows) get the size of the available screen and this is important to me because the size of each element of the application is calculated depending on height and width available on the screen, however when running on the ADV always returns 0x0 which prevents the correct application functionality.
If I try to deploy in a physical device, the debugger and the application does not even begin.
In the full log I get is this:

```
Debugging starts
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
I/dalvikvm( 4630): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no valid .odex file in the same directory
I/dalvikvm( 4630): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no valid .odex file in the same directory
I/dalvikvm( 4630): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no valid .odex file in the same directory
I/dalvikvm( 4630): Zip is good, but no classes.dex inside, and no valid .odex file in the same directory
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libgnustl_shared.so 0xb2d01db8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Core.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Core.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Gui.so 0xb2d01db8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Network.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Network.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Network.so 0xb2d01db8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Qml.so 0xb2d01db8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Quick.so 0xb2d01db8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Widgets.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Widgets.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Widgets.so 0xb2d01db8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Sql.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Sql.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Sql.so 0xb2d01db8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Positioning.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Positioning.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5Positioning.so 0xb2d01db8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0xb2d01db8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/local/tmp/qt/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so 0xb2d01db8
I/Qt      ( 4630): qt start
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/local/tmp/qt/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/local/tmp/qt/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so 0xb2d01db8, skipping init
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Shared lib '/data/local/tmp/qt/lib/libQt5QuickParticles.so' already loaded in same CL 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/local/tmp/qt/plugins/position/libqtposition_android.so 0xb2d01db8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/local/tmp/qt/plugins/position/libqtposition_android.so 0xb2d01db8
I/QtPositioning( 4630): Positioning start
D/dalvikvm( 4630): GC_CONCURRENT freed 189K, 9% free 2918K/3184K, paused 27ms+24ms, total 266ms
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/org.qtproject.example.appTurista-1/libappTurista.so 0xb2cda5c8
D/        ( 4630): (null):0 ((null)): QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.
D/dalvikvm( 4630): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/org.qtproject.example.appTurista-1/libappTurista.so 0xb2cda5c8
D/dalvikvm( 4630): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/org.qtproject.example.appTurista-1/libappTurista.so 0xb2cda5c8, skipping init
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: extra parameters: Bundle[{debug_ping=true, gdbserver_socket=/data/data/org.qtproject.example.appTurista/debug-socket, qml_debug=true, gdbserver_command=/data/data/org.qtproject.example.appTurista/lib/libgdbserver.so --multi +/data/data/org.qtproject.example.appTurista/debug-socket, qmljsdebugger=port:55091,block, ping_socket=org.qtproject.example.appTurista.ping_pong_socket}]
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: removing gdb socket /data/data/org.qtproject.example.appTurista/debug-socket
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: starting /data/data/org.qtproject.example.appTurista/lib/libgdbserver.so --multi +/data/data/org.qtproject.example.appTurista/debug-socket
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: gdbserver started
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: waiting for socket at /data/data/org.qtproject.example.appTurista/debug-socket, attempt 0
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: waiting for socket at /data/data/org.qtproject.example.appTurista/debug-socket, attempt 1
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: socket ok
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Debug socket accepted
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Waiting for debug socket connect
Could not load shared library symbols for 88 libraries, e.g. /system/bin/linker.
Use the "info sharedlibrary" command to see the complete listing.
Do you need "set solib-search-path" or "set sysroot"?Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: go to sleep
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Incoming socket OK
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: Got pid acknowledgment
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: ping not requested
I/Qt JAVA ( 4630): DEBUGGER: pong not requested
W/Qt A11Y ( 4630): Could not activate platform accessibility.
D/        ( 4630): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb7383e58, tid 4666
D/        ( 4630): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb73891a8, tid 4630
W/EGL_emulation( 4630): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
D/OpenGLRenderer( 4630): Enabling debug mode 0
D/libappTurista.so( 4630): (null):0 ((null)): QML Debugger: Waiting for connection on port 55091...
D/libappTurista.so( 4630): ../appTurista/manejadorbd.cpp:11 (ManejadorBD::ManejadorBD(QObject*)): (ManejadorDB)Apertura de base de datos local: false
D/libappTurista.so( 4630): ../appTurista/manejadorbd.cpp:24 (bool ManejadorBD::cargarDatosDBLocal()): (ManejadorDB)Cargando datos desde DB Local
W/libappTurista.so( 4630): (null):0 ((null)): QSqlQuery::exec: database not open
D/libappTurista.so( 4630): ../appTurista/main.cpp:20 (int main(int, char**)): Error al obtener tamaño de la pantalla.
D/libappTurista.so( 4630): No se puede continuar asi.
D/libappTurista.so( 4630): ../appTurista/globalcontrolclass.cpp:30 (virtual GlobalControlClass::~GlobalControlClass()): (GlobalControlClass)Borrando controlador Global
D/libappTurista.so( 4630): ../appTurista/manejadorbd.cpp:14 (virtual ManejadorBD::~ManejadorBD()): (ManejadorDB)Liberando de memoria lista de promociones y Bases de Datos
D/dalvikvm( 4630): threadid=12: thread exiting, not yet detached (count=0)
Debugging has finished

"org.qtproject.example.appTurista" terminated.
```

my main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <QDebug>
#include <QScreen>
#include <QQmlContext>
#include "globalcontrolclass.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    GlobalControlClass controlGlobal;

    QRect z = qApp->primaryScreen()->availableGeometry();
    controlGlobal.setWindowHeight(z.height());
    controlGlobal.setWindowWidth(z.width());
    if(z.height()<=0 || z.width()<=0){
        qDebug()<<"Error al obtener tamaño de la pantalla.\nNo se puede continuar asi.";
        return false;
    }
    qDebug()<<"Window Dip-> H:"<<controlGlobal.windowHeight()<<"W:"<<controlGlobal.windowWidth();

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ControlGlobal", &controlGlobal);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

I use Qt Creator 3.3.1 Qt 5.4.1 (GCC 4.6.1, 64 bit)
the AMV is ARM (armeabi-v7a) target: Android 4.4.2 (API level 19)

Comment: Which Qt and which Android versions are that?

Comment: sorry for not post that:
Qt Creator 3.3.1 Qt 5.4.1 (GCC 4.6.1, 64 bit)
the AMV is ARM (armeabi-v7a) target: Android 4.4.2 (API level 19)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve my problem in the following way.
change `qApp->primaryScreen()->availableGeometry();` for `qApp->desktop()->availableGeometry();`, and if I got the available screen size, This solution is important for the main function begins in the following way `QApplication app(argc, argv);`

main.cpp:

```
#include <QApplication>      // <== this is important
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

#include <QDebug>            // <= with the intention of testing

#include <QScreen>           // <== this is important
#include <QDesktopWidget>    // <==

#include <QQmlContext>
#include "globalcontrolclass.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    GlobalControlClass controlGlobal;

    QRect z = qApp->desktop()->screenGeometry();
    controlGlobal.setWindowHeight(z.height());
    controlGlobal.setWindowWidth(z.width());

    qDebug()<<"Window Dip-> H:"<<controlGlobal.windowHeight()<<"W:"<<controlGlobal.windowWidth();
    if(z.height()<=0 || z.width()<=0){
        qDebug()<<"Error al obtener tamaño de la pantalla.\nNo se puede continuar asi.";
        return false;
    }

    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("ControlGlobal", &controlGlobal);
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```